# Prove without using L'Hopital's rule that $f''(a)=0$ if $\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}}=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital, mean-value-theorem

I'm trying to prove without using L'Hopital's rule that $f''(a)=0$ if

$$\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}}=0,$$

assuming $f$ is twice differentiable and $f''$ is continuous. My first instinct was to use the mean value theorem to define a real number $t$ such that $f'(t)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, which gives $\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f'(t)}{x-a}}=0$. Since $t\to a$ as $x\to a$, this gives $f'(a)=0$, and

$$\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f'(t)}{x-a}}=\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f'(t)}{f'(x)}}\times\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f'(x)}{x-a}}=1\times f''(a)=0,$$

thus $f''(a)=0$. I wasn't entirely convinced, however, and quickly found counterexamples such as $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sin x^3}{\sin x}}=0$ (this doesn't exactly satisfy the mean value theorem, but I used this to disprove that $\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f'(t)}{f'(x)}}=1$ in general). Are there any additional steps I should be taking? Or should I take an entirely different approach (if even possible without L'Hopital's rule)?

Comment: Could you justify the claim "as $x->a$ $t->a$.

Comment: Since $t$ satisfies the mean value theorem, either $a<t<x$ or $x<t<a$, so $t\to a$ as $x\to a$

Comment: Ah you're right, I forgot to mention :P I wrote the entire thing under the assumption that $f''$ is continuous

Comment: You do not need the continuity of $f''.$ The existence of $f''(a)$ suffices.

Comment: @Coronium, if you are interested in a proof which uses the Mean Value Theorem, look at the addendum in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function has to be twice differentiable at $\,x=a\,,\;$ otherwise there is a counterexample.

Let $\;f:\,]\!-\!\infty,+\infty[\to\Bbb R\;$ be the function defined as follows

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^3\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)\;,&\text{ if }\;x\neq0\\\\\;0\;\;,&\text{ if }\;x=0
\end{cases}$

It results that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\,x\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=0$

but $\;f’’(0)\;$ does not exist, indeed

$f’(x)=\begin{cases}
3x^2\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)-x\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)\;,&\text{ if }\;x\neq0\\\\\;0\;\;,&\text{ if }\;x=0
\end{cases}$

and $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f’(x)-f’(0)}x= \lim\limits_{x\to0}\left[3x\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)-\cos\left(\dfrac1x\right)\right]$

does not exist.

---

Now, I will prove that $\,f’’(a)=0\,$ just assuming that there exists $\,f’’(a)\;$. It is not necessary that $\,f\,$ is twice differentiable at other points $\,x\neq a\,.$

**Taylor’s Theorem with Peano’s form of remainder :**
*If $\,f\,$ is a function such that there exists its second derivative $\,f’’(a)\,$ at the point $\,x=a\,,\;$ then $$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}2f''(a)+R(x)$$ where $\,R(x)\,$ is a function such that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{R(x)}{(x-a)^2}=0\,.$*

By applying Taylor’s Theorem with Peano’s form of remainder, we get that

$\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}=\dfrac{f’(a)}{x-a}+\dfrac{f’’(a)}2+\dfrac{R(x)}{(x-a)^2}\;.$

Since $\;\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{R(x)}{(x-a)^2}=0\;,\;$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\left[\dfrac{f’(a)}{x-a}+\dfrac{f’’(a)}2\right]=0\;,\;$ consequently ,

$f’(a)=f’’(a)=0\,.$

---

**Addendum :**

It is possible to prove that $\,f’’(a)=0\,$ just applying the Mean Value Theorem in the following way.

$f’(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)\!-\!f(a)}{x\!-\!a}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\left[(x\!-\!a)\dfrac{f(x)\!-\!f(a)}{(x\!-\!a)^2}\right]\!=\!0.$

Let $\,\delta\,$ be a real positive number ( $\delta\in\Bbb R^+$).
Let $\,g:[a-\delta,a+\delta]\to\Bbb R\,$ be the function defined as

$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\;\;,&\text{ if }\,x\in[a-\delta,a+\delta]\setminus\{a\}\\\\
f’(a)=0\;\;,&\text{ if }\,x=a
\end{cases}$

$g’(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}=0\,.$

The function $\,g\,$ is continuous and differentiable on $\,[a-\delta,a+\delta]\,$ and it results that

$g’(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f’(x)}{x-a}-\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}\;\;,&\text{ if }\,x\neq a\\\\
\;0\;\;,&\text{ if }\,x=a
\end{cases}$

Consequently ,

$\dfrac{f’(x)}{x-a}=g’(x)+\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}\;$ $\;\forall x\!\in[a\!-\!\delta,a\!+\!\delta]\setminus\{a\}.$

For all $\,x\in[a-\delta,a+\delta]\setminus\{a\}\,,\,$ by applying the Mean Value Theorem to the function $\,g\,$ on the interval $\,I_x\,$ ( where $\,I_x=[a,x]\,$ if $\,x>a\,,\,$ otherwise $\,I_x=\,[x,a]\,),\,$ we get that there exists $\,\xi(x)\,$ in the interior of the interval $\,I_x\,$ such that

$\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=g’\big(\xi(x)\big)\;.$

In this way, we get the function

$\;\xi(x):[a-\delta,a+\delta]\setminus\{a\}\to\;]a-\delta,a+\delta[\,\setminus\{a\}$

such that $\;\;\lim\limits_{x\to a}\,\xi(x)=a\;\;$ and

$g’\big(\xi(x)\big)=\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\;\;\;\;\forall x\in[a-\delta,a+\delta]\setminus\{a\}\,.$

Moreover ,

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{f’\big(\xi(x)\big)}{\xi(x)-a}&=g’\big(\xi(x)\big)+\dfrac{f\big(\xi(x)\big)-f(a)}{\big(\xi(x)-a\big)^2}=\\
&=\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}+\dfrac{f\big(\xi(x)\big)-f(a)}{\big(\xi(x)-a\big)^2}=\\
&=\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}+\dfrac{f\big(\xi(x)\big)-f(a)}{\big(\xi(x)-a\big)^2}\;\;,\quad\color{blue}{(*)}\\
&\forall x\!\in[a\!-\!\delta,a\!+\!\delta]\setminus\{a\}\,.
\end{align}$

From the equality $\,(*)\,,\,$ it follows that

$\begin{align}
f’’(a)&=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f’(x)\!-\!f’(a)}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f’(x)}{x\!-\!a}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f’\!\big(\xi(x)\big)}{\xi(x)\!-\!a}=\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\left[\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{(x-a)^2}+\dfrac{f\big(\xi(x)\big)-f(a)}{\big(\xi(x)-a\big)^2}\right]=\\
&=0+0=0\;.
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is twice differentiable at $a,$ the conclusion follows by a single application of l'Hopital rule. First observe that
$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)-f(a)\over (x-a)^2}(x-a)=0$$
Next
$$0=\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)-f(a)\over (x-a)^2}\overset{H}{=}{1\over 2}\lim_{x\to a}{f'(x) \over x-a}={1\over 2}\lim_{x\to a}{f'(x)-f'(a) \over x-a}={1\over 2}f''(a)$$
I do not see a simpler way. The proof of l'Hopital rule is based on the generalization of the mean value property to the ratios of the form $\displaystyle{f(x)-f(a)\over h(x)-h(a)}.$ In the OP case $h(x)=(x-a)^2.$

**Remark** There is a general theorem on [Peano remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) applied in the OP case for $k=2.$ T**he proof of that theorem relies on l'Hopital rule** applied $k-1$ times.

Answer (score 0):

By translation of the variable and values, we are reduced to prove that if $f''(0)=\ell$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=0$ then $\ell=0.$

The assumptions imply the following Taylor developement of $f$ at $0$:
$$f(x)=0+x\cdot0+\frac{x^2}2\ell+o(x^2)$$
and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac12\ell+o(1)=0,$ i.e. $\ell=0.$